# MenuFlyout - code an Item

Tags: c#, events, uwp, flyout

I just created a small flyout:

```
MenuFlyout flyout = new MenuFlyout();
flyout.Items.Add(new X_UWP_App.Models.MyMenuFlyoutItem() { Text = "Copy" });
flyout.ShowAt(rect);
```

I can mark a text. After the marking of the text this flyout appears with "Copy" in it.
Now I wondered how I could put some code behind "Copy"?

I was thinking of something like this, but it does not seem right.

```
public void onFlyoutItemClick(object sender, FlyoutItemClickEventArgs e)
{
    var dataPackage = new DataPackage();
    dataPackage.SetText(SelGetText());
    Clipboard.SetContent(dataPackage);
}
```

------ part above got answered. Under this line there is my next related question and answer ----

```
                var dataPackage = new DataPackage();
                dataPackage.SetText(m_view.vSelGetText());
                Clipboard.SetContent(dataPackage);
```

This is how those 3 lines really look. Note that m_view.vSelGetText() doesnt work. m_view is not assigned in this class. How could I achieve it so it is assigned. Because right now if I click on "Copy" it copies "Copy". This is the error I get: "An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property x.m_view"

Comment: What doesn't seem right about it?

Comment: I couldnt find an Event for the "FlyoutItemClickEventArgs"-substitute. I am not even sure if it works like this.

Comment: Quick suggestion. Try `Tapped` Event.

Comment: tried public void onFlyoutItemClick(object sender, FTappedEventHandler e) and public void onFlyoutItemClick(object sender, TappedRoutedEventArgs e).
both didnt work.
I might have misunderstood you, sorry if that is the case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You code looks correct, you have implemented `MyMenuFlyoutItem`, you could add the `onFlyoutItemClick` in your class like the following.

```
class MyMenuFlyoutItem : MenuFlyoutItem
{
    public MyMenuFlyoutItem()
    {
        this.Click += MyMenuFlyoutItem_Click;
    }

    private void MyMenuFlyoutItem_Click(object sender, Windows.UI.Xaml.RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        var dataPackage = new DataPackage();
        dataPackage.SetText(SelGetText());
        Clipboard.SetContent(dataPackage);
    }

    private string SelGetText()
    {
        return this.Text;
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi. This worked out but I have a new problem now (my fault, I havent given you enough code). I will edit my main post for this.

Comment: Doesn't this just set the clipboard to the word `Copy`...?

Comment: If you change the constructor to accept a string as your clipboard content, you can just set that as a class property assigned to at construction and ditch the `SelGetText` method, and just swap that out with your new string property for the clipboard content.